# Pdf output looks different when exported from InDesign vs CorelDraw?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, corel-draw

I have created a design in CorelDraw. While publishing it to PDF, it gets washed out. That might be due to some color management issue.

Now, when I'm create the same design in InDesign the PDF generates exact color and quality.

How can I be sure that this PDF generated from InDesign will print to paper as it is shown on screen in PDF ?

Comment: Please be aware that `pdf` viewers, all of them, are positively *horrible* at properly displaying a print-ready `pdf`. Don't trust what you see on-screen, trust what you made and trust the export settings in your lay-out program.

Comment: I created a new document with CMYK color and did the design, while publishing to pdf if I use Corel's predefined 'Prepress' i.e. output as CMYK, the colors looks washed out.

Whilist in InDesign I did the same thing and the pdf output was perfect.

Please note that I'm very new to color management.

Currently I have published the PDF with RGB color profile from Corel and the colors look quite perfect on pdf.

Comment: *"can I be sure that this PDF generated from InDesign will print to paper as it is shown on screen in PDF ?"* You can't. You have to calibrate everything, use proper profiles, export to a press-ready PDF format and then get a chroma key/color proof from the printer. Once you do this a few times you'll begin to trust your settings.

Comment: @Scott make that an answer.

Comment: @joojaa ... er..... m'kay

Comment: Then what will be the print output if I export the pdf with RGB color profile ? Another thing is what is 'Black overprint' ? This term has been mentioned by our press.

Answer (score 3):

> [How] can I be sure that this PDF generated from InDesign will print to paper as it is shown on screen in PDF ?

You can't.

There at least a dozen variables in the path from screen to press. You can not control all of them and it's entirely possible ones you *can* control are incorrect.

You have to calibrate everything - monitors, scanners - use proper profiles for all application and images - export to a press-ready (PDF) format and then get a chroma key/color proof from the printer.

Once you do this a few times you'll begin to *trust* your settings. However, there's never an absolute way to know that everything is perfectly correct until you see the file off the press compared to your screen.

I am *not* a Corel user. But I am a long time InDesign user. If you've got your monitor properly calibrated, your InDesign color settings correct, and exported to PDF/X format, chances are you're pretty close with the PDF generated from InDesign. However, only a chroma key or press proof will verify that.

Comment: +1 yeah you could add some links to calibration equipment so readers understand those are physical pieces of equipment not something you do with software or if you know a good link or so... anyway yeh what i would have said.

Comment: Then what will be the print output if I export the pdf with RGB color profile ? Another thing is what is 'Black overprint' ? This term has been mentioned by our press.

Comment: @hypheni Something random, unless your calibrated and know the cmyk profile of the printer and have a sane profile intent. If you care about your colors you calibrate and do the proofs, no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably lies with the fact that Corel Draw only allows CMYK formats and InDesign uses both RGB and CMYK.

When you export a file in a CMYK format and view it on a screen which is essentially an RGB screen everything looks dull or washed out.

If you're exporting the PDF to print, you shouldn't worry about the colors you see there, but if you're exporting a PDF just for digital usage, it would be better to use InDesign since you can export an RGB PDF too and the colours wouldn't look washed out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So you mean, though my PDF looking washed out on screen it will be print on paper as shown on Corel ? Actually I'm a bit concern as the printing press is totally 3rd party. I will pass the PDF to some guy and he will take the printout.

Comment: Yeah. That's right. You can always ask for a test page from the document to see how it looks. Essentially, colours can never be as saturated or bright as that observed on a digital screen. Eg. RGB Black appears blacker than CMYK Black as black on the screen is just absence of light, but on print, it doesn't function that way and is dependent on the K (Key Plate which is usually Black) part of CMYK. Hope that helps.

Comment: So, I should provide them a pre-press PDF whatever it looks.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Especially if this is the first time you're printing this document and are worried about how the colours turn out. Just remember RGB can produce more colours than CMYK can which is why CMYK colours look a little muddy. But while printing, CMYK is the format that the printing machine understands.

Comment: Yes, that I understand. CMYK for Print and RGB for Web. My point is, I created the doc in Corel with CMYK color profile and applied all the colors from CMYK palette only, then why color is changing after converting it to PDF.

Comment: If you used the CMYK colour format to design the whole thing, don't judge how the PDF looks like on the screen to determine what it will look in print. The best thing to do is to take a test print out first and see if the colours are drastically off.

Comment: Okay, will follow this. Actually the thing is before printing the PDF will be reviewed by people's eye. So I need to give them a RGB version as well as a print version. Is there any way to keep 1 version for both purpose. The PDF will be downloaded from a website too.

Comment: Since you designed it in CMYK, just changing the document colour format to RGB might not do the trick. Some colours will still remain washout and you will then manually have to edit the colours to make them look brighter. Changing from CMYK to RGB = RGB takes on the same CMYK colours as it can support them. But Changing from RGB to CMYK, there is a colour loss since CMYK can't support all RGB colours.

Comment: So what is suggested ? Make 2 version: 1. CMYK for print, 2. RGB for web ?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't have to but if you have finicky clients who don't understand these differences in colour formats. It's probably advisable. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification mate. And yes here the client is finicky. And moreover they need the same for both Web and Print use.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: One thing just came to mind. How InDesign produced output looking perfect in PDF while the CMYK color profile has been used in InDesign ?

Comment: InDesign in general is more compatible with RGB formats. It's just a software thing. Corel is strictly Print, InDesign is more versatile in that sense.